# LISP: how to trace macros

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

This is probably a stupid question, but I'm walking through the PG lisp book, and I wanted to step through some example macros that he provides with actual values, for instance:

```
(defmacro our-let (binds &body body) 
    `(
        (lambda ,(
                mapcar #'(lambda (x) (if (consp x) (car x) x)) binds
            )
                ,@body
        )
        ,@(mapcar #'(lambda (x) (if (consp x) (cadr x) nil)) binds)
    )
)
```

I naively tried to run `(trace our-let)` and then `(our-let ((x 1) (y 2)) (+ x y))` but I'm getting an error, `can't use encapsulation to trace anonymous function #<FUNCTION (MACRO-FUNCTION OUR-LET) {22675BBB}>`. Also not sure how to best put `print` statements into the lambdas. What's the best way to debug this macro/output how it's processing inputs?

EDIT(1): I had the incorrect formatting for `macroexpand`, which works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How you debug it:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(our-let ((x 1) (y 2)) (+ x y)))
; ==> ((lambda (X Y) (+ X Y)) 1 2) 
; ==> t
```

BTW your formatting is not good. Here is how it can look:

```
(defmacro our-let (binds &body body) 
  `((lambda ,(mapcar #'(lambda (x) (if (consp x) (car x) x)) binds)
      ,@body)
    ,@(mapcar #'(lambda (x) (if (consp x) (cadr x) nil)) binds)))
```

Or I would prefer:

```
(defmacro our-let ((&rest bindings) &body body) 
  (let ((names (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (if (consp x) (car x) x)) bindings))
        (exprs (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (if (consp x) (cadr x) nil)) bindings)))
    `((lambda ,names ,@body) ,@exprs)))
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm coming from the JS world, so I'm still getting my sea legs on formatting. I think the first of your examples is probably best, since the second one uses `let` to rewrite `let`.

Comment: @lispquestions if you are using emacs, you can try the [paren-face](https://github.com/tarsius/paren-face) to dim the parentheses.

Answer (score 6):

Actually being able to trace macros is not very common in Common Lisp implementations. Compilers will typically expand the macro forms during compilation.

A few implementations support it though - which makes sense when they also support a Lisp interpreter, which runs the actual source. Among those are LispWorks and CLISP.

Here using the code from Sylwester in CLISP:

```
  i i i i i i i       ooooo    o        ooooooo   ooooo   ooooo
  I I I I I I I      8     8   8           8     8     o  8    8
  I  \ `+' /  I      8         8           8     8        8    8
   \  `-+-'  /       8         8           8      ooooo   8oooo
    `-__|__-'        8         8           8           8  8
        |            8     o   8           8     o     8  8
  ------+------       ooooo    8oooooo  ooo8ooo   ooooo   8

Welcome to GNU CLISP 2.49.93+ (2018-02-18) <http://clisp.org/>

Copyright (c) Bruno Haible, Michael Stoll 1992-1993
Copyright (c) Bruno Haible, Marcus Daniels 1994-1997
Copyright (c) Bruno Haible, Pierpaolo Bernardi, Sam Steingold 1998
Copyright (c) Bruno Haible, Sam Steingold 1999-2000
Copyright (c) Sam Steingold, Bruno Haible 2001-2018

Type :h and hit Enter for context help.

[1]> (defmacro our-let ((&rest bindings) &body body) 
       (let ((names (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (if (consp x) (car x) x)) bindings))
             (exprs (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (if (consp x) (cadr x) nil)) bindings)))
          `((lambda ,names ,@body) ,@exprs)))
OUR-LET
[2]> (trace our-let)
;; Tracing macro OUR-LET.
(OUR-LET)
[3]> (dotimes (i 3)
       (our-let ((x (* i 10)))
         (+ x 3)))
1. Trace: (OUR-LET ((X (* I 10))) (+ X 3))
1. Trace: OUR-LET ==> ((LAMBDA (X) (+ X 3)) (* I 10))
1. Trace: (OUR-LET ((X (* I 10))) (+ X 3))
1. Trace: OUR-LET ==> ((LAMBDA (X) (+ X 3)) (* I 10))
1. Trace: (OUR-LET ((X (* I 10))) (+ X 3))
1. Trace: OUR-LET ==> ((LAMBDA (X) (+ X 3)) (* I 10))
NIL
[4]>
```

Answer (score 1):

A nice thing about CL is that its designers thought quite hard about some things.  In particular it turns out that you can trace macroexpansion portably in CL, thanks to [`*macroexpand-hook*`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_mexp_h.htm).  The code at the end of this answer uses it to trace macroexpansion  It makes some attempt to cooperate with anything else which might be talking to `*macroexpand-hook*`, and to avoid recursive tracing, but it's not very well tested.  There are controls for how much should be printed which have default values which are 'much less than everything'.

Here is an example of this in LispWorks:

```
> (macroexpand-traced-p)
nil

> (trace-macroexpand)
t

> (defun foo (x) x)
(defun foo (x) ...)
 -> (dspec:def (defun foo) (dspec:install-defun 'foo # ...))
(dspec:def (defun foo) (dspec:install-defun 'foo # ...))
 -> (compiler-let (#) (compiler::top-level-form-name # #))
(compiler::top-level-form-name (defun foo)
  (dspec:install-defun 'foo # ...))
 -> (compiler::tlf-name-binding (compiler-let #)
      (dspec:install-defun 'foo # ...))
(compiler::tlf-name-binding (compiler-let #)
  (dspec:install-defun 'foo # ...))
 -> (compiler-let (# #) (dspec:install-defun 'foo # ...))
(dspec:location)
 -> ':listener
foo
```

As you can see you get a lot of internal expansions which are probably not interesting.  To deal with this there is support for filtering the output so you don't see macroexpansions which may not be interesting to you, of which there are a lot.

Here is a filter function which tries to only show expansions where the thing being expanded is visible in the current package:

```
(defun trace-macroexpand-trace-this-package-p (macro-function macro-form
                                                              environment)
  (declare (ignore macro-function environment))
  (and (consp macro-form)
       (symbolp (first macro-form))
       (let ((name (first macro-form)))
         (eq (find-symbol (symbol-name name) *package*) name))))
```

And here is the some output for that:

```
 > (setf *trace-macroexpand-trace-p* #'trace-macroexpand-trace-this-package-p)
(setf *trace-macroexpand-trace-p*
      #'trace-macroexpand-trace-this-package-p)
 -> (let* (#) (setq *trace-macroexpand-trace-p* #:|Store-Var-1102|))
#<Function trace-macroexpand-trace-this-package-p 4060000844>

> (defun foo (x) x)
(defun foo (x) ...)
 -> (dspec:def (defun foo) (dspec:install-defun 'foo # ...))
foo
```

As you can see you only now get 'interesting' macroexpansions.  Cleverer filters could be defined, of course.

Here is the code:

```
(eval-when (:load-toplevel :compile-toplevel :execute)
  ;; macroexpansion tracing really wants to be off when compiling this
  ;; code as exciting things may happen during the evaluation of
  ;; DEFVAR &c otherwise.
  (when (fboundp 'trace-macroexpand)
    (ignore-errors                      ;don't barf
      (trace-macroexpand nil))))

(defvar *trace-macroexpand-print-length* 3
  "The value of *PRINT-LENGTH* used when tracing macroexpansions")

(defvar *trace-macroexpand-print-level* 2
  "The value of *PRINT-LEVEL* used when tracing macroexpansions")

(defvar *trace-macroexpand-trace-p* (constantly t)
  "Should we trace a given macroexpansion?

If this is bound to a function that function will be called with the
same three arguments that *MACROEXPAND-HOOK* takes, and should return
true if the expansion is to be printed.  Otherwise it should be true
if expansion is to be printed, false otherwise.")

(defvar *traced-macroexpand-hook*
  ;; the old value of *MACROEXPAND-HOOK*, used to restore it and to
  ;; know if we should trace.  Not user-adjustable.
  nil)

(defun trace-macroexpand (&optional (tracep t))
  "Trace or untrace macroexpansion.

If called with no argument, or an argument which is true, ensure that
macroexpansion is on.  If it was already on return NIL, otherwise
return T.

If called with an argument which is NIL then ensure macroexpansion is
not traced.  If it was traced return T else return NIL."
  (if tracep
      (if *traced-macroexpand-hook*
          nil
        (let ((hook *macroexpand-hook*))
          (flet ((macroexpand-hook (macro-function macro-form environment)
                   (if (if (functionp *trace-macroexpand-trace-p*)
                           (funcall *trace-macroexpand-trace-p*
                                    macro-function macro-form environment)
                         *trace-macroexpand-trace-p*)
                       (let ((expanded-form (funcall hook macro-function 
                                                     macro-form environment))
                             (*print-length* *trace-macroexpand-print-length*)
                             (*print-level* *trace-macroexpand-print-level*)
                             (*print-pretty* t))
                         (format *debug-io* "~&~S~% -> ~S~%" macro-form expanded-form)
                         expanded-form)
                     (funcall hook macro-function macro-form environment))))
            (setf *traced-macroexpand-hook* hook
                  *macroexpand-hook* #'macroexpand-hook)
            t)))
    (if *traced-macroexpand-hook*
      (progn 
        (setf *macroexpand-hook* *traced-macroexpand-hook*
              *traced-macroexpand-hook* nil)
        t)
    nil)))

(defun macroexpand-traced-p ()
  "Is macroexpansion currently traced?"
  (if *traced-macroexpand-hook* t nil))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to trace the macro that should work in any Common Lisp:

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (defun our-let-expander (binds body)
    `((lambda ,(mapcar #'(lambda (x) (if (consp x) (car x) x)) binds)
        ,@body)
      ,@(mapcar #'(lambda (x) (if (consp x) (cadr x) nil)) binds))))

(defmacro our-let (binds &body body)
  (our-let-expander binds body))
```

Now we just `(trace our-let-expander)`.

In my experience, complicated macros often end up handled via expander helper functions like this anyway, for various reasons.

(One big reason is this: as soon as you have two or more syntactic interfaces to the same expansion logic, you don't want to copy and paste that logic into multiple `defmacro` forms, but have it in a function.)

P.S. note the reformatting of the backquote form.  Do not separate opening parentheses from what follows, and have closing parentheses on lines by themselves.