# lisp: tracing a macro in an imported package

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

I'm the author of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59274015/lisp-how-to-trace-macros) SO question, which asks broadly how to expand / trace macros. Generally the responses that I've gotten there have worked for me.

I'm looking to better understand the internals of the Parenscript library, and towards that end, I wanted to trace through how the `ps` macro works.

Prior answers in the linked-to SO question aren't working here.

I've set up my environment as follows:

```
(defpackage "PS-TUTORIAL"
    (:use "COMMON-LISP" "HUNCHENTOOT" "CL-WHO" "PARENSCRIPT" "CL-FAD"))
(in-package "PS-TUTORIAL")
```

When I try to run something like `(trace ps)` or `(trace parenscript:ps)`, I get this error:

```
can't use encapsulation to trace anonymous function #<FUNCTION (MACRO-FUNCTION
                                                                  PS) {228E80EB}>
```

When I try to use `(macroexpand-1 '(ps (make-array 1 2 3)))`, I get a very shallow trace back:

```
"new Array(1, 2, 3);"
T
```

I'd like to see how the Parenscript compiler mechanism works in detail; what's the best way to get that set up here?

Comment: If you want to see how it works, read the source code. `TRACE` doesn't show the details.

Comment: Even if it worked, all you would see is lots of recursive calls like `In: 1 Out: "1" In: 2 Out: "2"`

Comment: Having also read the source code, I think that the recursive calls here would help me to understand what was going on.

Comment: What CL implementation are you using, there may be an implementation-dependent way to do it.

Comment: I'm running sbcl on OS X.

Comment: A comment at that questionmentions `(trace push :encapsulate nil)`.

Comment: Seems like that got rid of the error, but I'm not getting much of a trace back:   `0: ((MACRO-FUNCTION PARENSCRIPT:PS) (PARENSCRIPT:PS (MAKE-ARRAY 1 2 3)) #<unused argument>)
  0: PS returned "new Array(1, 2, 3);"`

Comment: It probably doesn't call itself recursively, it probably calls internal functions instead.

Comment: Ah, so I would have to add `trace`s on all of the internal functions to see how those behave as well.

Comment: Sure. If it were interpreted, you would use `STEP`, but that doesn't generally work with compiled code.

Comment: This is generally intended for use by the programmer to debug the internals of the code, so they know which functions to trace.